# Adding a DB Raw Query inside a query

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have a `$user = User::query()` and if statements checking if a user clicked on a certain checkbox.

If yes then I have a `$user->where(' ?? ')`

I made a big JOIN query using raw DB but how do I add a DB Raw to this query.

```
if ($request->type == 'test') {
   $user->where( DB::RAW(' ?? ') );
}

$user->get();
```

Comment: what is this magical ??

Comment: Before this, take a look a the SO's [how to ask article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It will help you in the future.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the `whereRaw` method.

```
if ($request->type == 'test') {
    $user->whereRaw('Your query goes here...');
}

$user->get();
```

Answer (score -1):

Figured this wouldn't be a good solution to my problem. `whereRaw` is not what I need. To solve. I grabbed all the IDs from my result query and then used a `WhereIn` to find the answer.

Comment: I think you should just delete this question because I don't see how this answers what you asked.  Work on making your questions more clear in the future.